# Does dijkstra works when I multiply weights of successive nodes

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

Consider a complete bidirectional weighted graph. Weight of each edge (a,b) is the probability of getting from a to b. So all weights are in range (0,1]. Probability of going from `a` to `b` through the pass `a-c-b` is `w(a,c)*w(c,b)`. So if I want to find the probability of getting to all the other nodes from `a` can I use multiplication instead of addition in dijkstra? Or should I convert multiplication to addition using `log`? More generally does dijkstra always work if the cost of the path always gets worse regardless of the function we use?

Comment: What do you think?  What are your thoughts?  Have you tried working through some examples and seeing what happens?  Have you tried making a conjecture and proving it?

Comment: @D.W. I have implemented both methods and it think there should be no difference between them. I have tested some inputs on it and they both gave the same result. But still I can't prove this.

Comment: Well, what have you tried, for trying to prove this?  Have you gone back to the original proof of correctness for the standard Dijkstra's, and trying to mimic everything you see there?  Where's the first place you get stuck?  Give that a try and see if you can formulate a more specific question.